# iPhone openssl not compiling

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-errors, openssl, xcode4.3

I am trying to compile the sample iphone openssl created by x2on here:
https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

I get the following errors when trying to compile in Xcode 4.3.3:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> ```
>  "_MD5", referenced from:
>
>      -[ViewController calculateMD5:] in ViewController.o
>
>  "_SHA256_Init", referenced from:
>
>      -[ViewController calculateSHA256:] in ViewController.o
>
>  "_SHA256_Update", referenced from:
>
>      -[ViewController calculateSHA256:] in ViewController.o
>
>  "_SHA256_Final", referenced from:
>
>      -[ViewController calculateSHA256:] in ViewController.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for a day or so and I am stumped on what to do.

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Have you done all the steps to include their library in your project? I am not familiar, but a quick search showed this, which is quite involved. Can you verify that the lib is properly included? http://www.x2on.de/2010/02/01/tutorial-iphone-app-with-compiled-openssl-library/

Comment: The steps mentioned couldn't execute so I imported the files from a later version of openssl. I'm not sure if it would still work or not but maybe it is some library issue. Still the libraries are linked to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out why it wasn't working. I never included the shared libraries in the same folder as my project and never linked the header search paths. After cleaning up my project and rebuilding it recognized the Openssl library and it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2010-May/136571.html), it indicates that you need to link with `libcrypto`.